# Create a constructor with parent class as parameter

Tags: c#

I don't know how to define my question (probably already asked but didn't found it).

I want to create a constructor for a class B inherited from A taking a B object as parameter used to be a copy of it.

There can be something like this :

```
class B : A
{
    public String NewField;

    public B(A baseItem, String value)
    {
        // Create new B to be a copy of baseItem
        ???; // something like : this = baseItem

        // Add new field
        NewField = value;
    }
}
```

Objective is to create an object B which is the exact copy of an A object with on filed more.

Comment: `this` is read-only within classes, add a copy constructor to `A` and call it from B's constructor.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor

Comment: I know I can't assign this, I want to initiate the new B object to be a copy of the `baseItem`.

Comment: With `A` having a copy ctor, you'd do `public B( A baseItem, string value) : base( baseItem ) { NewField = value;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [base](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base) keyword to call the parent class constructor, giving your parent class instance as a parameter. Then create a [copy constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor) in your parent, and you're done.

```
class A
{
    public A(A a)
    {
        // Copy your A class elements here
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public String NewField;

    public B(A baseItem, String value)
     : base(baseItem)
    {
        NewField = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a `CopyProperties` method, which will copy the properties values.

using System;

```
public class A
{
    public string Filename {get; set;}

    public virtual void CopyProperties(object copy)
    {
        ((A)copy).Filename = this.Filename;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public int Number {get;set;}

    public override void CopyProperties(object copy)
    {
        base.CopyProperties(copy);
        ((B)copy).Number = this.Number;
    }    
}


public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        B b = new B { Filename = "readme.txt", Number = 42 };

        B copy = new B();
        b.CopyProperties(copy);

        Console.WriteLine(copy.Filename);
        Console.WriteLine(copy.Number);
    }
}
```